# How to overwrite default props of a higher order component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, higher-order-components

I have a higher-order that have these default props:

```
defaultProps = {
    className: null,
    duration: 400
};
```

Now I have another component e.g. `<InnerBox />` that is using this higher-order component as an extension. How do I overwrite from within `<InnerBox />` the values of the defaultProps in my higher-order component?

When I tried doing the same from within `<InnerBox />`:

```
static defaultProps = {
   className: "classnameforthiscomponent"
   duration: 300
};
```

It doesn't work. The reason I am defining a different default component for the  is because this component is being generated by the Router (that is set-up on another file) so I cannot pass props to it from outside as in:

```
<InnerBox 
  duration={300}
  className="classnameforthiscomponent"
/>
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: "this component is being generated by the Router so I cannot pass props to it from outside" [You can do](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func) `<Route render={(props) => (<InnerBox duration={300} />)} />` unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: @catandmouse you want to define the default props of the higher order component based on InnerBox defaultProps?

Comment: In render of InnerBox,pass default properties to child component.

Comment: @Teneff Yes correct..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I overwrite from within `<InnerBox />` the values of the defaultProps in my higher-order component?

imo. you can't, because `<InnerBox />` doesn't know how it was invoked.

And once it got its `props` it doesn't know where they came from; passed as props to the HOC or defaultProps or whatever; at least that's how it's supposed to be.

You either provide the ability to pass the `defaultProps` alongside the component you want to wrap for this HOC

```
const wrapper = (component, defaultProps) => // your HOC
```

Or your HOC could use the defaultProps of the wrapped component

```
//maybe like 
const wrapper = (component) => {
  return class {
    static defaultProps = Object.assign({}, HOC.defaultProps, component.defaultProps);
  }
}
```

Or you  or you don't use `defaultProps` at all in this HOC.

either:

```
render(){
  let props = {
    ...defaults,
    ...InnerBox.defaultProps,
    ...this.props
  }
  return <InnerBox {...props} />;
}
```

Or you just pass through the `props`, don't use `HOC.defaultProps` but now the wrapped components have to deal with possibly undefined props.

---

Anyways, you have to fix the HOC. `InnerBox` can not manipulate the component it is wrapped in. The HOC needs to consider the component it is wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Since your higher order box depends on InnerBox you should import it

```
import InnerBox from './path'

class HigherOrderBox {
  static defaultProps = {
    // here you can destruct InnerBox.defaultProps
    ...InnerBox.defaultProps,
    // or just a single property,
    duration: InnerBox.defaultProps.duration
    // and you can also have
    additionalProperty: true
  }
}
```

if you don't need additional properties you can define

```
static defaultProps = InnerBox.defaultProps;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your higher order component inside of function, and pass props in it:

```
export default (outerProps) => {
   return (ComposedComponent) => {
       class MyHOC extends Component {
          // inside stuff of HOC
       }
       MyHOC.defaultProps = {
          className: outerProps.className || null,
          duration: outerProps.duration || null
       }

       return MyHOC;
   }
}
```

And, when using your HOC with InnerBox:

```
MyHOC({ 
   className: 'my-custom-class',
   duration: 600
})(InnerBox)
```

Hope this helps